# Formal verification with 'KeY' in Java fails to prove array reset loop

Tags: java, formal-verification, jml, key-formal-verification

Currently I'm trying to grasp a little bit of [formal verification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KeY) with the *[KeY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KeY)* tool for Java programs.

Here is my key-annotated Java code:

```
public class Test {
    public int[] a;

    /*@ public normal_behavior
    @ ensures (\forall int x; 0<=x && x<a.length; a[x]==1);
    @*/
    public void fillArray() {
        int i = 0;
        while(i < a.length) {
            a[i] = 1;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

To my surprise *KeY*, it fails to prove that the current program is valid according to its specification. *KeY* fails at goal 54. Current goal window shows:

```
 self.a.<created> = TRUE,
 wellFormed(heap),
 self.<created> = TRUE,
 Test::exactInstance(self) = TRUE,
 measuredByEmpty
==>
 self.a = null,
 self = null,
 {exc:=null || i:=0}
   \<{
         try {
             method-frame(source=fillArray()@Test, this=self)
             : {
                 while (i<this.a.length) {
                   this.a[i] = 1;
                   i++;
                 }
               }
         }
         catch (java.lang.Throwable e) {
             exc = e;
         }
     }\> (\forall int x; (x <= -1 | x >= self.a.length | self.a[x] = 1) & self.<inv> & exc = null)
```

I don't really comprehend: What is the main cause of failing to prove the specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic reason of failure was that if the prover found an unbounded loop in a method - then it couldn't follow a method specification without a [loop invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant) specification.

Thus for each unbounded loop we must specify a loop invariant. A loop invariant is some rule which holds true **for each** loop iteration. Every loop can have its own specific invariant rule. So Java code with specification must be fixed to:

```
public class Test{

  public int[] a;

  /*@ public normal_behavior
  @ ensures (\forall int x; 0<=x && x<a.length; a[x]==1); // method post-condition
  @ diverges true; // not necessary terminates
  @*/
  public void fillArray() {
    int i = 0;

    /*@ loop_invariant
    @ 0 <= i && i <= a.length &&  // i ∈ [0, a.length]
    @ (\forall int x; 0<=x && x<i; a[x]==1); // x ∈ [0, i) | a[x] = 1
    @ assignable a[*]; // Valid array location
    @*/
    while(i < a.length) {
      a[i] = 1;
      i++;
    }
  }

}
```

The hardest part in thinking about how to specify method will be to find-out a loop invariant. But at the same time - it's most interesting. For the sake of reason I'll repeat this loop's invariant:

> i  ∈ [0, a.length]
>   x ∈ [0, i) | a[x] = 1

And this condition never changes in the loop in **ANY** iteration. That's why it is an *invariant*.

BTW, if formal specification is *done right* - we can throw away [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) and unit testing out out the window. Who cares about run-time results if program can be mathematically proven to be correct according to its specification?

If the specification is good and code semantics is *proven* - then **nothing** can go wrong in program execution - that's for sure. Because of that - formal validation is a very promising field.

Comment: A side remark: Coming up with a suitable loop invariant can be quite cumbersome, especially if the program is not necessarily correct. KeY also offers the option to do "Loop Expansion", that is, repeated loop execution like you know it from concrete execution. For this, you however need an upper bound for your array size (like mentioned by Agnius, for *unbounded* loops you have to specify an invariant). Add a "requires a.length <= 10;" (or some other number) and tick "Expand" for "Loop Treatment" in the KeY strategy options. Thus, you can do some validation first before proving the program.